# import jackrabbit api aem 6.3

Tags: jsp, aem, jackrabbit

Im just starting with AEM, and need to create users programmatically. There is a number of resources online that leverage the User Manager class, however it seems like I cannot import the jackrabbit libs into my JSP file:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.UserManager" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.UserManagerFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.Authorizable" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.profile.Profile" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.sling.commons.json.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.commons.TidyJSONWriter" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Authorizable"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Group"%>


<%@ page contentType="application/json" %>

<%

  response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");


String email = request.getParameter("email");

    JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(response.getWriter());
    writer.object();
    writer.key("Email");
    writer.value(email);
    writer.key("Code");
    writer.value("fred");
    writer.endObject();
%>
```

When i add the jackrabbit libs, the jsp fails. I checked system/console/bundles, and they seem to be there.

Comment: don't use JSPs for this sort of thing (or anything) - create an OSGI service instead and get an instance of the `UserManager` by adapting it from a resolver: `resolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);`

Comment: Thanks, to elaborate I just want to create a quick and dirty Json endpoint to crud crx users. If I were to keeping jsp in a crx environment how would I go about adding this Library which i thought was already part of the AEM stack ?

Comment: what is the error?